# ASP.NET MVC 2's Model Validation outside the context of your views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, mobile

I was reading this blog post on [ASP.NET MVC 2's new model validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) and found it to be pretty cool.  I see the value in keeping things DRY by adding a couple attributes to a class property and then automagically getting client and server side validation (as long as your controller checks for valid models).

That said, imagine an ASP.NET MVC application in a greater context.  Perhaps I have an ASP.NET MVC application with this validation and all, but then I want to expose things to new clients, like an iPhone or Android application (not just a mobile browser).  I would have to write some web-services or something that use the same underlying repositories/services that my ASP.NET MVC app uses.  Could I re-use this validation stuff?

Wouldn't I have to re-write the client-side validation?  I don't see a way around this, since I'll be shipping off serialized objects to be de-serialized into non-C# classes from Objective-C or whatever.

Wouldn't I also have to re-write the server-side validation?  Is there some way for me to call into the ModelState on an object outside the context of an ASP.NET MVC controller (e.g., as part of the web-services I create to talk to mobile clients).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx), they are not part of MVC actually. So you can use them elsewhere as you wish.

There are [other work extending them - annotationscontrib is one of them](http://annotationscontrib.codeplex.com/) and I guess you can look at how, for example ModelBinder is implemented and write your own service using that.

[xVal Project](http://xval.codeplex.com/) is possibly doing along the same lines as what you are after - converting the validation rules into Javascript. Unfortunately I am not sure how much effort you need to adapt xVal for your project or rewrite it.

As for running the validations on the annotated classes one can use the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator_members(VS.95).aspx) (thanks [womp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63756/womp))

Comment: Yes, it's using Data Annotations. But first, can I use these in any way outside of c# (e.g., in objective-c for iPhone).  And second, how to I validate an object based on it's Data Annotations?

Comment: You need to use reflection and scan your annotated classes.

Comment: @Maxwell:  Seems weird that I'd have to reflect in myself.  I'll keep looking, but that is something I can write if I need to, and share amongst the web services.

Comment: @Maxwell - that is incorrect.  You can use the Validator class to manually run validation on data annotations.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator_members%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: @womp - thanks.  I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try later.  That will at least allow me to easily validate objects coming in from the web services.

Comment: Thanks womp. Sorry about the rubbish reflection comment. Should I delete it?